# How to search for a specific key in a json file in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, python-requests, key

I am solving a python problem in which I have to request a JSON file of the current status of bitcoin and from that, I have to fetch the current price of USD, I am stuck on the part where I have to fetch the rate from JSON file which is deep inside some dictonaries which contains a lot of data and I don't know how to get a specific key from them ...
here is my code sample (currently I just want to fetch the USD rate and print it)

```
import sys
from urllib import response
import requests
import json

if len(sys.argv) == 1 :
    sys.exit("missing argument!")
elif type(float(sys.argv[1])) != float :
    sys.exit("argument is not number")
    
response = requests.get("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")

o = response.json()
print()
```

and here an example of json file...

```
{
  "time": {
    "updated": "Aug 16, 2022 18:13:00 UTC",
    "updatedISO": "2022-08-16T18:13:00+00:00",
    "updateduk": "Aug 16, 2022 at 19:13 BST"
  },
  "disclaimer": "This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org",
  "chartName": "Bitcoin",
  "bpi": {
    "USD": {
      "code": "USD",
      "symbol": "&#36;",
      "rate": "23,960.8828",
      "description": "United States Dollar",
      "rate_float": 23960.8828
    },
    "GBP": {
      "code": "GBP",
      "symbol": "&pound;",
      "rate": "20,021.5220",
      "description": "British Pound Sterling",
      "rate_float": 20021.522
    },
    "EUR": {
      "code": "EUR",
      "symbol": "&euro;",
      "rate": "23,341.3982",
      "description": "Euro",
      "rate_float": 23341.3982
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the keys as indices.

```
o["bpi"]["USD"]["rate"]
```